# How does the process of creating a new secure Elliptic Curve look like?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, tls, ed25519, x25519

I'm especially curious about the technique djb would have used to come up with his Curve 25519. Say I have already written down my goals, such as - Twist Secure, Speed, Side Channel resistance, etc. In this case, how do I go about creating new curves? Are there specific algorithms that Cryptographers / Mathematicians use? Or is it just improvising on similar work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you said, you need to define the goals. You can take a look at [SafeCurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/), which is a joint work by Bernstein and Lange to help choose/construct elliptic curves w.r.t. ECDLP difficulty and ECC security. Note that if you need a pairing-friendly elliptic curve you need to look at other criteria related to the embedding degree. You can read [this paper by Freeman et al.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/372.pdf) for different constructions. Now talking about Curve25519, Bernstein explained his choices [in his paper](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf). These are some of the main points he mentioned in a talk:

- Curve25519 has a large prime char field because current CPU multipliers include fast floaing-point multipliers and extension fields punish CPUs with another multiplier size.
- Curve25519 has a Montgomery shape $y^2=x^3+Ax^2+x$ with tiny $A \in 2+4\mathbb{Z}$ because one can do projective $x$-coordinate doubling and addition together using 1 field multiplication by $(A-2)/4$, 4 field squarings and 5 extra field multiplications without needing $y$ coordinate.
- Curve25519 uses prime very close to a power of 2. Specifically, $2^{255}-19$ instead of a Solinas prime like $2^{256}-2^{224}+2^{192}+2^{96}-1$ because repeated addition is more costly than multiplication by 19.
- Curve25519 uses a secure curve of order $8 \times \text{prime}$ with a secure twist $y^2=x^3+486662x^2+x$ of order $4\times \text{primes}$.
- The $A$ is chosen so that $(A-2)/4$ is a small integer to speed up multiplication by $(A-2)/4$ (formulas [here](https://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom-xz.html)) and so that the twisted curve order is either $4 \times primes$ or $8 \times primes$. The smallest positive choices were then 358990, 464586 and 486662. Bernstein rejected 358990 and 464586 because one of their prime factors is slightly smaller than $2^{252}$ and discussing the question on how one should handle the theoretical possibility of a secret key matching the prime is harder than simply moving to the last choice $A=486662$ ([Nothing up my sleeve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number)).

Comment: Is 486662 really a NUMS number? It was chosen based on its objective mathematical properties.

Comment: it is considered a NUMS with respect to the two other choices, but not a NUMS in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Really appreciate the details @YoussefElHousni 

I also came across this interesting paper on deterministic generation of EC. https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/130.pdf